# Wordpress: display list of users

Tags: wordpress, templates, posts

I want to create a page template where I can display users with their avatar and their posts from  two different roles (Admin and Author).

Comment: Whats wrong with this question?

Comment: Are you looking for individual pages for each of these users, or a list of all matching users on one page?

Comment: I need all list in one page from two specific user roles. eg, custom role 1, and custom role 2. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here, they have it documented pretty well on the wordpress documentation along with a sample.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Author_Templates